# Can I ban a player in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there any possibilty I can take in order to ban people from League of Legends. This concerns people who **intentionally feed**, giving the opposite team a huge advantage, because those people ruin the game and waste the time of their teammates.

Comment: Oh someone is salty lol

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is just a rant.

Comment: You can - just right clicking on the player name, select `block`

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot ban a player in League of Legends, however you can report them in the post game screen for a number of different reasons, and they may be banned or otherwise penalized. To report someone click the red exclamation point to the right of there name, and fill out the report like below.
[image]

Comment: Note: False reporting is punishable as well. Please don't start reporting your whole team on the account of people not playing well or being out classed.  The difference between feeding/trolling and being out played is difficult to see when you're in the middle of a match.  Unless they say something in chat that backs up their actions, it's safer to give the benefit of doubt to your team.

Comment: @NBN-Alex False reporting is punishable now ? I knew they could just ignore your reports but punishing you ?

Comment: I need to find the original location I've read it from, but even [LoL's own reporting page](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/player-behavior/reports-how-do-they-work) talk about accounting for false reports and working to crack it down.  There's no hard set punishment from what I can find, but the context of the question suggests that the reporting might not be used in good faith.

Comment: My understanding was enough false reports and they start weighing your reports less and less

Comment: Something to add, which is really nice, is that once the player gets punished, you will get a notification (either in game or through email, i'm not sure if it has been changed to email, or if it's dependent on how long the punishment comes after reporting)

Comment: @Aequitas You won't get it every single time I think, if you are one of the last ones to report him you will, but if you catch him in the first few offense nothing will notify you. That notification is basically "Your report finished the job on him"